# I sent a bundle of data by using bulkTransfer, but received data in pieces

Tags: java, driver

I used 2 USB to TTL cp21xxx boards to connect 2 phones. I sent the data as in the first pic. I received the data on another phone as in the second pic:
[1ST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM6Sm.png)
[2ND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5LUD.png)
All the drivers are referenced from github (3RD PIC). I don't know why the data I received was in pieces.
[3RD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j06KS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also copy the code into the question. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)